# Colon before switch syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I encountered a syntax I've never seen before:

```
A:switch(a)
    {
    case a1: 
        switch(b)
        {
        case b1:
            doB1();
            break; 
        default: 
            doDefault();
            break A;
        }
        // fall through
    case a2:
        doA2()
        break;
    }
```

The part that bugs me is the colon before switch in `A:switch(...)` and `break A`. Is there a name for this syntax? Where can I find documentation on this syntax?

Comment: It's a [labeled break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: Thank you @FedericoklezCulloca